# No cast although cast operator is defined

Tags: c++, templates, casting, typecast-operator

Can someone please help me to understand why the following code does not compile:

```
template< typename T >
class A
{};

template< typename U >
class wrapper
{
  public:
    // cast operator
    operator wrapper< A<void> > ()
    {
      return wrapper< A<void> >{};
    }

};

template< typename T >
void foo( wrapper< A<T> > )
{}


int main()
{
  foo(  wrapper<void>{} );
}
```

error message:

```
t.cpp:24:7: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
      foo(  wrapper<void>{} );
      ^~~
t.cpp:18:10: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'A<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'void'
    void foo( wrapper< A<T> > )
         ^
1 error generated.
```

and how to fix it?

I expected that `wrapper<void>` is casted to `wrapper< A<void >` using the cast operator of `class wrapper`.

Comment: To fix it perform explicit static cast, so the template parameters deduction will receive correct type. It looks like you've assumed that template parameters deduction will take into account possible user-defined conversions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `foo`-s template deduction fails because the of the implicit cast.

- `foo` tries to deduce type T
- P = `wrapper<void>`, A = `wrapper<A<T>>`
- `foo` has no possible way to deduce what `A<T>` is

So, we have to help `foo` deduce T.

**Solution 1**

Let `foo` know what is T explicitly:

```
foo<void>( wrapper<void>{} );
```

**Solution 2**

Cast `wrapper` to `wrapper< A<void> >` explicitly to let `foo` know what T is:

```
foo( static_cast< wrapper< A<void> > >(wrapper<void>{}) );
```

Comment: The question is why the deduction fails? It works with template< typename T=void> as well as with void foo( wrapper<T> ) ?

Answer (score 3):

You can fix it by explicitly cast `wrapper< void >` to `wrapper< A<void> >` using `static_cast` as shown in the following:

```
int main()
{
  foo( static_cast< wrapper< A<void> > >(wrapper<void>{}) );
}
```

which compiles smoothly.

---

Note that template deduction does try to match the template parameters exactly without doing conversions. It means that if a cast is necessary in order to make things match exactly then the cast has to be explicit.